# Can't maximise Minecraft window

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing in Minecraft in full screen for a while (toggling using <kbd>F11</kbd>) and then after a while, I went back to windowed mode (I don't like playing in full screen, I was just testing the functionality of it for... reasons).

However, when I went to maximize the window (not full-screen) I realized the maximize box in the corner had become disabled. I fiddled with full screen a bit more, toggling it in the menu options as well as toggling it with <kbd>F11</kbd>, but this had no effect. Restarting Minecraft (closing it completely and re-opening, not just quitting to menu) did fix it however.

Does anyone know what causes this issue, and if restarting Minecraft *is* the only way to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is caused by of 1.8 because you can maximize in other versions.
The only way I have been able to fix it myself is restarting the game.

Make sure when you restart the game that in the menus your fullscreen is set to off. If not you'll get the same problem every time you restart.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Launcher
2. click "edit Profile" Button
3. activate Checkbox "JVM Arguments"
4. next to this checkbox remove the string "-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy"
5. save Profile
6. click "Play"
7. ???
8. Profit

...now the maximize button is enabled.

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly what this does?

Comment: Restarting didn't help, removing that string didnn't help... :'D

Comment: This is NOT what that flag controls. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/gc-ergonomics.html

Answer (score -2):

Exit out minecraft and press play and when the Mojang symbol pops up rapidly click the maxi button that is how It fixed for me

Answer (score -3):

This is a common problem everyone gets, it happens to me (I have Windows 8, Minecraft 1.8.7).

Restarting will always work.